# How to order by column with non-null values first in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a sql statement to select all users ordered by lastname, firstname.  This is the part I know how to do :)  What I don't know how to do is to order by non-null values first.  Right now I get this:

null, null
null, null
p1Last, p1First
p2Last, p2First

etc

I need to get:

p1Last, p1First
p2Last, p2First
null, null
null, null

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

See [Sort Values Ascending But NULLS Last](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Sort_Values_Ascending_But_NULLS_Last)

basically

```
SELECT *
    FROM @Temp
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN LastName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, LastName
```

Answer (score 12):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the
`IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )`

will suit too.

`ORDER BY IIF(name IS NULL, 1, 0), name`