# SQL Server 2005: Order with NULL values at the end

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Case Order by using Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498240/case-order-by-using-null)

I'm looking to get a list of records ordered by an "ordernum" field.  The ordernum field is an int field.  This field starts as NULL until set by a user.  I would like the NULL entries to appear at the end of the list.

I am building a query as follows:

```
select *, case when (ordernum is null) then [largestInt] else ordernum end as newordernum
from tableName
order by newordernum
```

I know I could enter the value for the largest possible int for [largestInt], but I would like to replace [largestInt] with a variable.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found a way to order NULL values on the bottom.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/denis_gobo/archive/2007/10/19/3048.aspx

It meets my needs quite nicely.  My query is now:

```
select *
from tableName
order by case when ordernum is null then 1 else 0 end, ordernum
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it. But I find it weird that your answer was posted at almost the exact same time that your question

Comment: I was Googling at the same time.  It's really difficult to search for things like "max int" without getting the aggregate function.  It's possible to post a question with answer at the same time, which is what I did.  :)

Comment: I know its possible, no problem with that. But this question is actually a duplicate that has been answered many times here on SO, so a quick search here would've returned this same thing

Comment: @Lamak It is true what dangowans says, look at this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Lamak but you are right also, I searched in SO with a fragment of the question title and found this in less than a minute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807361/how-to-order-by-column-with-non-null-values-first-in-sql Answer your own question is intended as a way of adding some missing piece of knowledge to stackoverflow.

Comment: I apologize for the duplication.  I didn't find the duplicates originally because I was looking for a way to select the largestInt, not to order with NULLs at the end.  While working through the question, I figured out what I was really looking for.  Sorry.