# DataGridView sorting with nulls in Decimal column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The problem is that null value is greater than decimal value 0.00, so the sorting problem arises in ascending order.

```
Private Sub dgvTable_SortCompare(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs) Handles dgvTable.SortCompare
    If e.Column.Index = 4 Then
        e.SortResult = System.Decimal.Compare(todecimalnull(e.CellValue1), todecimalnull(e.CellValue2))
    End If

    e.Handled = True
End Sub

Function todecimalnull(ByVal cellvalue)
    If cellvalue = "" Then
        Return "0.0"
    Else
        Return cellvalue
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: i want null first then 0.0000 by using above code, plz help me asap

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest populating the datagrid view using 0 instead of null. 
There may be reasons to leave value null, but those may weigh less than the sorting issue.

This is a nice SO thread about sorting with non null values first.

[How to order by column with non-null values first in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807361/how-to-order-by-column-with-non-null-values-first-in-sql)

A custom sort may be in required - as opposed to clicking the column, or overload the sort column to apply this logic. (Is this possible?)